# Google Account deleted due to TOS violations

Tags: google-account

I receive the following email:

[image]

Is there any way to know what part of the TOS I am supposed to have violated?

Comment: Short of going through the [Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/) point by point to see what you might have done, the only people who can answer that is Google. However, I think there's a decent chance that this is a phishing attempt. Does your account still work?

Comment: @AlE. The account doesn't work anymore. It wasn't a phishing attempt (see the key icon right and the left of the sender meaning the sender has been verified), but for once I wish it was :-) I don't care about this account, but it makes me having doubts on using Gmail as an email address provider.

Comment: I'm here because I received a similar email today. Tried signing in to the said account. It reads something like "this account is deleted", and on trying the recovery page, it reads, "Google doesn't provide another way to sign in to this account". No idea what TOS I violated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Google never tell the user which clause of the TOS were infringed, so you have to check yourself what was done with your account.